# If I earned a privilege and then lost the required reputation to get that privilege would I lose that privilege

Tags: support, privileges

I was wondering if I earned a privilege such as upvoting and I then started to loose enough points (like someone else downvoting my questions and answers) would I lose that privilege?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you lose the privilege but things that you've done while having that privilege (such as voting on posts) remain.

If you regain the lost rep you regain the privilege except that you won't get another congratulatory message about it in your inbox since you've already had one.